extension pg_cron on PostgreSQL DB on Google Cloud Platform Cloud SQL not working on monthly and weekly schedule
I installed pg_cron extension (v.1.4 ) on GCP Cloud SQL PostgreSQL (v.14) .
I instaleld it on postgres database and it works smoothly on daily schedule
E.G.
SELECT cron.schedule('test cron OK', '21 18 * * *', 'VACUUM (FULL, VERBOSE) cron.job');
SELECT cron.schedule('test cron OK', '21 * * * *', 'VACUUM (FULL, VERBOSE) cron.job');

But when I schedule on monthly or weekly bases the job will not run (I can't find any attempt logged in  cron.job_run_details or errors in database logs ) :
E.G.
SELECT cron.schedule('test cron KO', '49 19 * * 4', 'VACUUM (FULL, VERBOSE) cron.job');
SELECT cron.schedule('test cron KO', '21 18 5 * *', 'VACUUM (FULL, VERBOSE) cron.job');

Do you have any idea what is the reason of this behaviour ?
Thank you,
Paolo

The problem is that Cron dates of the month start from 2 for June for example. June 2nd in Cron on RDS with Postges would be * * 3 jun *
I have tested it, don't ask me how I got there but this is what works.

You can check if the job is created using the following command:
select * from cron.job;

If you're able to see the job. kindly wait for the job to run before listing listing cron.job_run_details

Job is created correctly.
I wait for a long time but the job will not be executed unless the schedule ends with '...* * *' ( daily schedule )
